# Using Spring Boot on a Closed Network

Tags: spring-boot

I'm very interested in being able to use Spring Boot, but I'm at a road block at work. I have to work in a closed network, with no internet access. Spring Boot is heavily dependent (or wholly dependent?) on Maven or Gradle from what I can tell. I can't find any references on how to use Boot without those build tools, and instead using ant.

One thought I had was to create a local Nexus repository for Maven, but I'm still restricted by that closed network, so I would have to manually download each and every dependency, and then again if I wanted an updated jar or file. That kind of defeats the purpose of Maven.

I was wondering how you might create a simple boot application in an offline/closed Network without the use of Maven or Gradle, and instead using a pure ant build process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find any references on how to use Boot without those build tools, and instead using ant.

There's a section on using Ant in the Spring Boot [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-build-an-executable-archive-with-ant). In general, I would say you are severely hampered if you can't use a modern dependency management system, whatever languages and frameworks you are using for your application (Java, node, python, ruby, etc.). So there are zillions of people in the same situation, and I'd be surprised if you couldn't find a way to use Maven or Gradle. In any case Boot (and Spring) are not in any way tied to those things; it just happens that there are some plugins that make using them easier.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll check it out and let you know how it goes. FYI: I HAVE to use ant. I can't argue that Maven or Gradle wouldn't be better (I do want them), but it's out of my hands.

Comment: I seems now that anything I end up doing with boot is going to end up in its own project and build, so the actual tool is now entirely up to me(ant, maven, gradle etc). I've been digging more into gradle, and I think I can use that for boot, even offline, using some local file repositories (ivy?). The link to the reference guide answers my main question, and I wouldn't have found it without Dave's help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do in a closed network is to setup your own Maven repository using Nexus. If you have an unused computer or a server that can run 24/7, you can install a Nexus repository there and point to it. Another way you can do is to manually download the required JAR files and keep it in local with the project folder and point to the local path with build.gradle. But in the second case, if you do that, the whole benefit of Gradle is kinda lost.

Comment: I was eventually able to convince IT to allow Nexus OSS to run as a proxy to some specific external repositories. This allowed me to take full advantage of Gradle and Spring Boot.